# Delete new line margin BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, margins

I need bibliogrpahy look like in first picture.
[image]

Actually, default look like in second picture.
[image]

diplom.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,russian,oneside,final]{extreport}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\bibliographystyle{styles/belarus-specific-utf8gost780u}

\begin{document}

~\cite{book_1}
~\cite{book_2}
~\cite{book_3}
~\cite{book_4}

\bibliography{bibliography_database}

\end{document}
```

bibliography_database.bib

```
@BOOK{book_1,
  title = {“Introducing Adaptive, Aware, and Cognitive Radios.” In Cognitive Radio, Software Defined Radio, and Adaptive Wireless Systems},
  publisher = {AA Dordrecht: Springer},
  year = {2007},
  author = {Fette, Bruce},
  pages = {1-16},
  language = {russian},
  owner = {mstyura},
  timestamp = {2013.03.18}
}

@BOOK{book_2,
  title = {Implementation issues in spectrum sensing for cognitive radios Signals, Systems and Computers},
  publisher = {Conference Record of the Thirty-Eighth Asilomar Conference.},
  year = {2004},
  author = {Cabric D. AND Misha S.M. AND Brodesen R.W.},
  pages = {772–776},
  language = {english},
  owner = {mstyura},
  timestamp = {2013.03.18}
}

@BOOK{book_3,
  title = {Теоретико-игровая модель распределения ресурсов в самоорганизующихся системах когнитивного радио // Сборник тезисов, материалы Пятнадцатой Всероссийской научной конференции студентов-физиков и молодых ученых (ВНКСФ-15, Кемерово – Томск)},
  publisher = {издательство АСФ России},
  address = {Екатеринбург – Кемерово},
  year = {2009},
  author = {Ошмарин Д.В.},
  pages = {672–673},
  language = {russian},
  owner = {mstyura},
  timestamp = {2013.03.18}
}

@BOOK{book_4,
  title = {Auction driven dynamic spectrum allocation: optimal bidding, pricing and service priorities for multi-rate, multi-class CDMA},
  publisher = {IEEE 16th International Symposium},
  year = {2005},
  author = {Rodriguez V. AND Moessner K. AND Tafasolli R.},
  pages = {1850–1854},
  language = {english},
  owner = {mstyura},
  timestamp = {2013.03.18}
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have used as a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: update the post

Comment: it's the `.bst` (i.e., "bibliography style") file that needs changing, so knowing (as we now do) where it is on _your_ file system doesn't help.  put it somewhere we can examine it on the web.